# XCode: My .h file is not detected

Tags: xcode, ios5, header

I would like to share some screenshots to well explain my problem.
[image]

[image]

As you can see at left of the images that BookCell.h file is present and when I am using #import its getting auto suggested. But fact is I can not use it at all. The BookCell.m is not finding BookCell.h, even in second screenshot as you can see,I have imported it to another class file,but that's also not able to find it! What's the problem?

I have tried reopening XCode and even restarted my mac. I need your help badly.

**EDIT**
Here goes the BookCell.h file:

```
//
//  BookCell.h
//  BookShelf
//
//  Created by ManGoes Mobile on 24/7/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ArticleCell.h"
#import "ArticleTitleLabel.h"
#import "MainViewDelegate.h"
#import "ControlVariables.h"
@interface BookCell : ArticleCell
//This image name will be needed once we want to retain the represented Article object by this.
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *imageName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UITableViewCell *parentCell;
@property CGPoint locationInCell;
-(BookCell *)BookCell;
//delegates
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<MainViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Comment: Please show the contents of BookCell.h also.

Answer (score 0):

How about Right-click on .h file and Remove Reference ,then add it to project again ?